# How do I plot the frequency of an event overtime with pandas?I

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I was trying to plot some data from a pandas dataframe.
My table contains 10000ish films and for each of them two info: the year it got published, and a rating from 0 to 3.
I am having a hard time trying to plot a graph with the pandas library that shows the number of films that received a particular rating (3 in my case) every year.

I have tried to use .value_counts(), but it didn’t work as i hoped, since I can’t isolate a single value, maintaining the rating linked to its year.

I really hoped i decently explained my problem, since it is the first time i ask help on stack overflow.

This is the code i used to get my dataframe, if it is useful in any way.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

request = requests.get("http://bechdeltest.com/api/v1/getAllMovies").json()
data = pd.DataFrame(request)
```

P.S. Thank you for the precious help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by `rating` and use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = data.loc[data['rating'].eq(3), 'year'].value_counts()
```

But there is many years of films:

```
print (len(s))
108
```

So for plot I filter only counts greatwer like 30, it is `40` years here:

```
print (s.gt(30).sum())
40
```

So filter again and plot:

```
s[s.gt(30)].plot.bar()
```

EDIT: Solution with percentages:

```
s=data.loc[data['rating'].eq(3),'year'].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index().mul(100)
print (s)  
1899    0.018218
1910    0.018218
1916    0.054655
1917    0.054655
1918    0.054655
  
2018    3.169976
2019    3.188195
2020    2.040445
2021    1.840044
2022    0.765167
Name: year, Length: 108, dtype: float64


print (s[s.gt(3)])  
2007    3.042449
2009    3.588996
2010    3.825833
2011    4.299508
2012    4.153762
2013    4.937147
2014    4.335945
2015    3.771179
2016    3.752960
2017    3.388595
2018    3.169976
2019    3.188195
Name: year, dtype: float64

s[s.gt(3)].plot.bar()
```

EDIT1: Here is solution for count `years` vs `ratings`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(data['year'], data.rating)
print (df)

rating   0   1   2    3
year                   
1874     1   0   0    0
1877     1   0   0    0
1878     2   0   0    0
1881     1   0   0    0
1883     1   0   0    0
    ..  ..  ..  ...
2018    19  44  24  174
2019    16  47  18  175
2020    10  17  11  112
2021    11  22  13  101
2022     3  14   5   42

[141 rows x 4 columns]
```

EDIT2:

```
df = pd.crosstab(data['year'], data.rating, normalize='index').mul(100)
print (df)
rating           0          1         2          3
year                                              
1874    100.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000
1877    100.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000
1878    100.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000
1881    100.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000
1883    100.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000
           ...        ...       ...        ...
2018      7.279693  16.858238  9.195402  66.666667
2019      6.250000  18.359375  7.031250  68.359375
2020      6.666667  11.333333  7.333333  74.666667
2021      7.482993  14.965986  8.843537  68.707483
2022      4.687500  21.875000  7.812500  65.625000

[141 rows x 4 columns]
```

There is alot of values, here is e.g. filter for column `3` for more like 60% values:

```
print (df[3].gt(60).sum())
26

df[df[3].gt(60)].plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked perfectly! What if i want to plot the percentage each year instead of the quantity?

Comment: @TommasoDonato - Use `.value_counts(normalize=True)` instead `.value_counts()`

Comment: Wait I’m sorry, i just noticed that the way you did it the x axis is not ordered, what if i want the years in a progressive order?

Comment: @TommasoDonato - Use `s = data.loc[data['rating'].eq(3), 'year'].value_counts().sort_index()`

Comment: Sorting the indexes worked out perfectly, but when i set normalize=True it gives me an IndexError

Comment: @TommasoDonato - Added to answer, need filter by e.g. `s[s.gt(3)]`, because percentage

Comment: @jezreal - what if instead of the percentage overall i want to plot the percentage of 3s among the film that were released that year?

Comment: @TommasoDonato - this is exatly this, first filter by `3` by `data.loc[data['rating'].eq(3),'year']` and then percentages `.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index().mul(100)`

Comment: if i do it this way isn’t the percentage shown relative to all the films released that got voted 3? What if i want each column to represent the percentage of 3s over 0,1 and 2 just for that single year?

Comment: @TommasoDonato - Do you think `3s over 0,1 and 2` it means `3 to sum 0,1,2` ratings?

Comment: My goal would be to understand if the percentage of 3 ratings increases or decreases year after year, but if i just count the number of 3s, or their distribution, the result is strongly influenced by this: data["year"].plot(kind="kde", figsize=(8,4), xlim=(1875,2025))          Sorry but i don’t know how to show code in comments

Comment: @TommasoDonato - I add `EDIT1`, e.g. for last rows what should be plot? `4.687500  21.875000  7.812500  65.625000` ? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, the best would be to have different graphs: one for each rating. In the graph about the 3s i wanna show the 65.625 for the year 2022

Comment: @TommasoDonato - added EDIT2

Comment: Honestly, I don’t know how to thank you. You made my day.